# Putting html/css animated element on top of header

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this:

```js
 var myIndex = 0;
    carousel();
    
    function carousel() {
      var i;
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";  
      }
      myIndex++;
      if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
      x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
      setTimeout(carousel, 3000); // Change image every 2 seconds
    }
```

```css
.downArrow{
  background-color: transparent;
    text-align: center;
}
.bounce {
  background-color: transparent;
    -moz-animation: bounce 3s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: bounce 3s infinite;
    animation: bounce 3s infinite;
}
@-moz-keyframes bounce {
  0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  40% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-30px);
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-15px);
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
}
@keyframes bounce {
  0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  40% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-30px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-30px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-15px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-15px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="headerr" class="home">

    <div class="w3-content w3-section">
    <img class="mySlides" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1629199022827-eede3c3df471?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwyfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60" style="width:100%">
    <!-- <a href="#about" class="button btn btn-defeault btn-send">Learn More!</a> -->
    <!-- <button class="button ahref-learn-more" type="button">Learn More!</button> -->
      <div class="downArrow bounce">
      <img width="40" height="40"  alt="" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" />
    </div>
    </div>
     
  </div>
```

however, right on the image, I want that dancing animated arrow instead of below it. how can I do this? I tried forcing it with the `em` using css, but it doesn't work, and just keeps everything on the left side, as well as doesn't adjust the height :

```
left: 10em;
bottom: 10em;
```

but it doesn't make any difference. thx 4 the help

Comment: Where specifically on the image should the arrow be positioned? It might help to include a working example of the problem to demonstrate how it goes wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work with absolute positioning. That way you can position your arrow relatively to the parent.

Here, I've marked the `w3-content` class to be relative and `downArrow` to be absolutely positioned, relatively to `w3-content`. With `left: 50%` the image is moved to start at the horizontal center of the container, with `margin-left: -20px` the image is moved back half of its width (40px) to have it perfectly in the center, and with `bottom: 10px` it's positioned 10px above the bottom of the container.

I've also added a red border to make it better visible in this example.

```css
.w3-content {
    position: relative;
}
.downArrow {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -20px;
    bottom: 10px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="headerr" class="home">
    <div class="w3-content w3-section">
        <img class="mySlides" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1629199022827-eede3c3df471?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwyfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60" style="width:100%">
        <div class="downArrow bounce">
            <img width="40" height="40" alt="" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now add your animation again and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it in the middle:

```js
var myIndex = 0;
    carousel();
    
    function carousel() {
      var i;
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";  
      }
      myIndex++;
      if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
      x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
      setTimeout(carousel, 3000); // Change image every 2 seconds
    }
```

```css
.sec {
  position: relative;
}

.downArrow{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 45%;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
}
.bounce {
  background-color: transparent;
    -moz-animation: bounce 3s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: bounce 3s infinite;
    animation: bounce 3s infinite;
}
@-moz-keyframes bounce {
  0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  40% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-30px);
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-15px);
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
}
@keyframes bounce {
  0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  40% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-30px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-30px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-15px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-15px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="headerr" class="home">

    <div class="w3-content w3-section sec">
    <img class="mySlides" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1629199022827-eede3c3df471?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwyfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60" style="width:100%">
    <!-- <a href="#about" class="button btn btn-defeault btn-send">Learn More!</a> -->
    <!-- <button class="button ahref-learn-more" type="button">Learn More!</button> -->
      <div class="downArrow bounce">
      <img width="40" height="40"  alt="" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" />
    </div>
    </div>
     
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

check this code

```
<div id="headerr" class="home">
          <div class="w3-content w3-section" style="display: flex;">
            <img class="mySlides" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1629199022827-eede3c3df471?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwyfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60" style="width:100%">
            <!-- <a href="#about" class="button btn btn-defeault btn-send">Learn More!</a> -->
            <!-- <button class="button ahref-learn-more" type="button">Learn More!</button> -->
              <div class="bounce1">
                 <img class="bounce1"width="40" height="40"  alt="" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.